# How to lock a SQL Server datatable against INSERT all the time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently debugging a datatable issue, in a very complex project. I want to find out which code modules inserted rows to this data table.

To find out who might insert rows to this data table, I want to **lock down** the entire datatable and see which code modules will fail (I hope it will fail when trying to insert rows to the data table as it has been locked down).

Is there a way to lock down a SQL Server 2016 database table so that no code can **INSERT** rows into it?

I tried to delete this data table, but it will fail too, if some code modules just do **SELECT**.

Comment: Scream Tests are my favorite. I'm not a SQL Server expert, but naively I feel like a trigger would be useful for this. You can write a trigger that is activated before update or insert to just `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and end. [Maybe something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/804173/trigger-to-reject-or-accept-an-update-or-insert) without the `if/else` block since you want to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` on everything.

Comment: A `DataTable` is the name of a class in ADO.NET. When you refer to DataTables do you just mean "table"?

Comment: Assuming your application is using it's own database user, and it's not sa or dbo (As it should), you can use `DENY INSERT ON OBJECT::<schema>.<table> TO <application_database_user>;`

Comment: The best thing is to Deny permission to the table. If you can't, you should lock table  with the TRAN (don't recommend)

Comment: Why not run SQL Server profiler OR Extended events to capture the queries being run when inserts happen?